# Authenticate/login to CKAN from JavaScript

Tags: ckan

I'm making a javascript client that reads data from ckan using the ckan.js api.
This works just fine when accessing data that does not need authentication.

I see that I can make authenticated calls if I provide the API key. But how do I authenticate/log in from javascript so that I can get the API key ?
in the doc it says

> When calling an API function that requires authorization, you must authenticate yourself by providing your API key with your HTTP request. To find your API key, login to the CKAN site using its web interface and visit your user profile page."
>   http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/api/#authentication-and-api-keys

It seems that I must manually log in to get the API key.

This will not work as the javascript client I'm making is not using the ckan interface.

Does anyone have a tip on how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the only built-in mechanism for authenticated use of the CKAN API is via API keys. This means that the user of your client will need to provide their API key to your client. The user can get their API key by logging into CKAN via the web UI and visiting their profile. Depending on the security context of your client, the client may store that API key so that users don't have to re-enter their keys all the time.

CKAN allows you to customize authentication using plugins, so it is possible to implement other authentication schemes. However, these would only work for CKAN instances that have the corresponding plugin installed and enabled.

For example, [ckanext-oauth2](https://github.com/conwetlab/ckanext-oauth2) provides support for authentication via OAuth2. However, I have no experience with that plugin and don't know whether it also supports OAuth2 authentication for API calls or only for the web UI.